# Trying to change which animations to play based on variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am trying to basically create a div that slides out using transforms, as those work best in Chrome. I'm using a plugin called Animo.js that uses .css classes to animate using jquery, but I can't seem to get my code right. I'd rather not use class toggles or jquery toggles of any sort.

Code example

```
$(document).ready(function()


var $hTog = 0


$('#home').click(function()
{
    if( $hTog.val() == 0)
    {
        $('#hSlider').animo({animation: 'hGrow', iterate: 1, duration: 10, keep: true, timing: 'linear'});
        $hTog.val() == 1;
    };
    else
    {
        $('#hSlider').animo({animation: 'hShrink', iterate: 1, duration: 10, keep: true, timing: 'linear'});
        $hTog.val() == 0;
    };
})
})
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `.val()`? Also you need to add a curly brace at the end of the `ready()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you can do in your code try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // the '{' not there add this
    var $hTog = 0;
    $('#home').click(function(){
       if( $hTog == 0){
          $('#hSlider').animo({animation: 'hGrow', iterate: 1, duration: 10, keep: true, timing: 'linear'});
          $hTog = 1;
       }else{
          $('#hSlider').animo({animation: 'hShrink', iterate: 1, duration: 10, keep: true, timing: 'linear'});
          $hTog = 0;
       }
   });
});
```

---

1. Remove `.val()` from the if conditions.
2. Remove the `;` from the closing of if condition and else part too.
3. Also after the `.animo()` method runs update the value of var with removing `.val()` and you don't need `==` to update the values.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This worked perfectly. I figured it was just a matter of syntax. Still learning.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing .val(), but you assigned $hTog the value 0, without properties. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hTog = 0
  $('#home').click(function() {
    if (hTog === 0) {
      $('#hSlider').animo({animation: 'hGrow', iterate: 1, duration: 10, keep: true, timing: 'linear'});
      hTog = 1;
    } 
    else {
      $('#hSlider').animo({animation: 'hShrink', iterate: 1, duration: 10, keep: true, timing: 'linear'});
      hTog = 0;
    }
  });
});
```